# How to instantiate correctly a cube prefab?

Tags: unity, vector

In a FPS i'm trying to instantiate cube like the old good minecraft.
The problem is that the first cube i instantiate on terrain got y=0 but half of that cube is underground ...
All my cube prefab are 1x1x1.

How to fix this problem ?

```
 void BuildBlock(GameObject block)
 {
     if (Physics.Raycast(shootingPoint.position, shootingPoint.forward, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
     {

         if (hitInfo.transform.tag == "Block")
         {
             // Instance over other cube
             Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.x + hitInfo.normal.x / 2), Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.y + hitInfo.normal.y / 2), Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.z + hitInfo.normal.z / 2));                
             Instantiate(block, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity, parent);
         }
         else
         {
             // Instance on terrain
             Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.y), Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.z));
             Instantiate(block, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity, parent);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is your game in a grid layout? And if it is half in the ground, it takes the middle of the cube for the location.

Comment: No, it's not in a grid layout..

Comment: This is missing a few informations. What is not working with the existing answer? How should a cube spawn on a slope? If the cube has to rotate, that's way more complicated compared to part of it can be inside the slope. If everything else in your code is as you want it, all you need to do is 0.5 upwards offset. Since the cubes have a fixed dimension, this can be a fixed value. Or if you have them as a prefab, you can adjust the pivot.

Comment: Your goal is to achieve this without using a grid layout?
If so, I have made a similar system in a Tower Defence game before and I wouldn't mind providing an answer.
If not and you'd like to create a cube placement system like the one in Minecraft, I recommend you look at the answer provided by agone.

Comment: "No, it's not in a grid layout" then why are you using `Mathf.RoundToInt` which snaps the position to a regular grid? Try to explain or illustrate what behaviour you want and we can match that. Presumably you already considered adding 0.5 to the y to lift the bottom of the cube up to the hit point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that Pivot point is in center of every unity primitive, like a cube.
To solve, I can create an empty object with pivot point in the bottom corner, than a child cube.
Now it works

Answer (score 0):

> No, it's not in a grid layout.

All objects upon creation need to align to a fixed sized grid.

The code for alignment (assuming a 40x40 grid):

```
 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.x * 40+19)/40, Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.y * 40 + 39.9f)/40, Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.z * 40 + 19)/40);
```

The 'y + 39.9f` gives the vertical alignment on the square above the trace, where the other two axis are centered to the grid.